# Datatable function for specific column

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I'm using DataTables to populate a table with results from a JSON request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json;",
  ...,
  success: function(data){

    var dataTblValues=$('#someTable').dataTable({
      "aaData": data.someList,
      "aoColumns": [
        {
          // Date
          "mData": "date"
        },
        {
          // Severity (I want some HTML output here depending on the severity)
          "mData": "severity"
        },
        {
          // Type
          "mData": "type"
        },
      ],
      "columnDefs" :[
        {
          "targets": 3,
          "data": null,
          "defaultContent": '<a href="#">Some link</a>'
        }
      ]
    });
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

#### What I want to do

The value of the second column ("Severity") is numeric, such as 1 or 2. Instead of just populating the value (1, 2 etc) directly in the column, I want to output something like:

```
<div class="severity-one">High</div>
```

...or

```
<div class="severity-two">Medium</div>
```

...depending on the severity.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for column 2 "severity"

```
"columnDefs" : [
                 {
                   "targets" : 1, // 1 because column count in dt starts from 0.
                   "render" : function(data, type, row) { 
                                      if(data==1) 
                                      { 
                                        return "<div class='severity-one'>High</div>"
                                      }

                                     if(data==2)
                                     {
                                       return "<div class='severity-two'>Medium</div>"
                                     }
                                                      }
                 }
              ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the data received via AJAX and transform those 1 and 2 in `<div class="severity-one">High</div>` or `<div class="severity-two">Medium</div>`.

Once transformed you just append it to the table via the usual way:

```
success: function(data){
var data_already_parsed = ;//parse data somehow, without knowing how data is formed it's impossible to give ideas.
var dataTblValues=$('#someTable').dataTable({
      "aaData": data_already_parsed,
...
```